# Download a file to a path when running headless mode in Chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, watir, google-chrome-headless

I'm using the following versions:

- Ruby 2.4.1
- chromedriver 2.33
- selenium-webdriver 3.7.0
- watir 6.7.3
- page-object 2.2.2
- Chrome browser 62.0.32

The env.rb file contains the path for the download directory.
When running the test **NOT** in headless mode the file downloads perfectly, but when I am running it headless nothing happens and the file does not download.
I was using chromderiver 2.27 and Chrome Browser 58.* and it worked in both modes, does anybody know how can I overcome that?

Answer (score 12):

So here's what I found and it definitely worked!

in the env.rb file when I configure the parameters for the headless mode, I defined it as such:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless') 
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1366,768')
options.add_preference(:download, directory_upgrade: true,
                                prompt_for_download: false,
                                default_directory: DOWNLOAD_DIR)

options.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })

$browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

bridge = $browser.send(:bridge)
path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id
bridge.http.call(:post, path, cmd: 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
                            params: {
                              behavior: 'allow',
                              downloadPath: DOWNLOAD_DIR
                            })
```

Thank you comment 89 in the Chromium's bugs webpage:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481

Comment: Quick question: on what system did this work for you? (It works for me on Mac but not Ubuntu so far.)

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? The versions are listed above in the question :)

Comment: There is no OS specified in the question, so I am just curious to know if you managed to have that solution work on Linux. (In the chromium thread people do a really poor job of specifying what OS they are using, and get different behaviors on different systems).

Comment: Oh yes I have, the OS I’m using is Centos 7.

Comment: Thanks for the precision!

Comment: It does actually.

Comment: your solution, the browser is created from selenium not from watir, if it is from watir it should be like this right?: `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    browser = Watir::Browser.new driver`

Comment: My current environment is running Watir with the configurations you just mentioned and the configurations I used in this thread.

Comment: @JaisAnasrullohJa'fari `Watir::Browser.new $browser` will you get a watir browser. Thanks for the snipped @theRubyGuy

Answer (score 0):

At this point it isn't supported. Headless was implemented without any of the chromium code that handles preferences. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775911

Comment: I see.
Is there a workaround? if not, what are the latest versions to use in order to make download happen?
Thank you

Comment: It isn't the version, it's the headless. If you use it without headless it will work. If you need headless, use headless gem with xvfb.

Comment: I am using xvfb but it still won't download while running headless.

Comment: What capabilities are you sending?

Comment: At the moment Im not, just the options.add_argument('--headless'). What would you recommend?

Comment: Either use headless gem with xvfb, or pass headless command, not both

Comment: i tried removing the xvfb and keeping the argument and it didn't solve it. what would you configure on the if ENV['HEADLESS'] condition if I do want to use the xvfb as i did before?
At the moment it's configure like that:  require 'headless'
  headless = Headless.new
  headless.start
  at_exit do
    headless.destroy
  end